# Width on <span> tag is undefined

Tags: html, width

I am creating a menu and the width of my  elements isn't working.

```
    width = 100/numMenus-1;
            alert(width) // I have 4 menu items so I get 24 here
        document.write('<span class=menuBar style="TEXT-ALIGN:center;width:' + width + '%;"'); 
        document.write('onmouseout=dTimeout=setTimeout("hideMenus(' + theMenu.num + ')",200) ');
        document.write('onMouseOver=dTimeout=setTimeout("showMenus(' + theMenu.num + ')",200) ');
        document.write('id=menuHeading' + theMenu.num + '>');
        document.write(theMenu.name);
        document.write('</span>');
            alert(menuHeading0);// I get [object HTMLSpanElement]
            alert(menuHeading0.width); // I get undefined.
```

and menu items are all bunched up in the center of the  containing them.  The class "menuBar" doesn't contain a width, only colors and font sizes.

Comment: You may want `menuHeading0.style.width`. See [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/xc3x4bwo/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The width doesn't affect inline elements. Set `display:inline-block;` on the spans and you should be in business.

```html
<span style="width:300px;background:red">Inline</span>
<span style="width:300px;display:inline-block;background:yellow;">Inline Block</span>
```